# Laravel 5.4 elequent create method generate wrong query

Tags: laravel

I am trying to insert data in a table using eloquent create method, But data which I have passed not coming in insert query generated by create method. Due to which I am getting a default value error. 
Below are the code i have used

Model :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PasswordReset extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'token'];
}
```

Controller :

```
$content = ['email'=>'test@gmail.com', 'token'=>'1234'];
PasswordReset::create($content);
```

Error I am getting :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'email' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `password_resets` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2018-09-25 16:16:45, 2018-09-25 16:16:45))

Why query in above error does not have 'email' and 'token' fields?

Comment: what happens if you replace protected $fillable = ['email', 'token']; with protected $guarded = [id]?

Comment: Your error is weird, it's like if you did a `PasswordReset::create([])`. are you sure you dont have anything resetting `$content` ?

Comment: @amini.swallow getting same error.

Comment: Is this your entire model file class ? is `$content` used as shown ?

Comment: @N69S, There is no code which resetting $content

Comment: Please post the whole `PasswordReset` model and the code that builds `$content` in your application.

Comment: @cbaconnier, Thanks, After looking your comment. I have checked with my code and its having a __construct method without having any code within it and removing this resolve the issue.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir so, in the end you had something that resets the $content (ignores it in fact) :) happy you found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your comment:

> @cbaconnier, Thanks, After looking your comment. I have checked with my code and its having a __construct method without having any code within it and removing this resolve the issue.

If you want to use `__construct()` on the `Model`, you need to build it like this

```php
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create like this

```
PasswordReset::create([
  'email'=>'test@gmail.com',
  'token' => '1234'
]);
```

Comment: What's the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
$passwordReset = new PasswordReset();

$passwordReset->email = 'test@gmail.com';

$passwordReset->token = '12345';

$passwordReset->save();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this i hope work for you :

```
    PasswordReset::create([
'email'=>'test@gmail.com',
'token' => '1234']);
```

Comment: please test that and this for model instead of fillable
 : protected $guarded = [ ]

Comment: if it was a `$fillable` issue, the error would be `MassAssignementException` not an SQL error